Change title (verbose name plural) in custom admin.TabularInline
In my Django admin UI I use a TabularInline like this:
class MyCustomInline(admin.TabularInline):
    # ...
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        # ...

The overridden functions adds a filter, so that only a subset of related objects is displayed. In the admin UI I get table using the plural of the model class as title, which is wrong in this case. I would like to give it a custom name.
I cannot do this for the model itself, because I want to change the title only for this filtered set. Not for the model class in general.
I tried to figure it out from the source code. In the template I found out that the verbose_name is passed in via opts, but could not follow its path to find a way to override it.
Could somebody give me a hint how to change the title aka verbose name just for this specific TabularInline?

You can inject it in the extra_context:
class MyCustomInline(admin.TabularInline):
    # …
    def _changeform_view(self, request, object_id, form_url, extra_context):
        return super()._changeform_view(
            self,
            request,
            obj_id,
            form_url,
            {**extra_context, 'title': 'sample-title'},
        )

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        # …

Does not work for me. Seems like the method is not called at all.

@Achim: can you edit the question with a screenshot what title you want to change?
